# onMouseOver JavaScript with CSS list-style-image

Tags: javascript, html, css, minecraft

I'm curious - is there a way to add a onMouseOver element in JavaScript to a CSS list-style-image (image for bullet point). Here's my code:

```
<style type="text/css">
ul.one {list-style-image:url('http://fun.resplace.net/Emoticons/Minecraft/Diamond.png');}
</style>
```

That is interacting with this:

```
<ul class="one">
<li class="one"><input type="button"  id="1"onclick="show_prompt()" value="Minestatus" /></li>
<li class="two"><input type="button" id="2" onclick="show_alert()" value="Minecraft Server List" /></li>
<li class="three"><input type="button" id="3" onclick="show_alert1()" value="MCSL" /></li>
</ul>
```

And I want to make it so that when someone mouses over the diamond, it shows a message other than this:

```
<p>Please vote for my server!</p>
```

Also, this is part of my Minecraft server's website's vote code that I'm developing, in case you were wondering what this entire thing is. I want to make it so that when you scroll over one of the diamonds, other than 'Please vote for my server', it would say the website name that they would be voting for. Thanks for any help, it's much appreciated :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mouse event cannot distinguish between the bullet point and the li because they are one and the same.

Instead, you should replace the bullets with an li background + padding and then add a message container that is expanded/shown on mousehover.

Alternatively you can make a separate container for the diamond itself that contains a message that is revealed on hover. The message container can of course have anything you want in it.

This can be done without any javascript involvement.

While on the subject, you should not use [inline event handlers](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_early.html). You should be attaching events through javascript, thus separating HTML and Javascript. It is easier to manage, it looks better, and it's more stable.

The [traditional event registration model](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html) and the [advanced registration model](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html) should bring you up to speed on that point.

---

### [First example](http://jsfiddle.net/uZjz9/1/) | Code

HTML

```
<ul class="one">
    <li class="one">
        <div class='diamond'>
            <div class='message'>Please vote for me!</div>
        </div>
        <input type="button"  id="1"onclick="show_prompt()" value="Minestatus" />
    </li>
    <li class="two">
        <div class='diamond'>
            <div class='message'>Please vote for me!</div>
        </div>
        <input type="button" id="2" onclick="show_alert()" value="Minecraft Server List" />
    </li>
    <li class="three">
        <div class='diamond'>
            <div class='message'>Please vote for me!</div>
        </div>
        <input type="button" id="3" onclick="show_alert1()" value="MCSL" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul.one {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

ul.one li .diamond{
    background: url('http://img835.imageshack.us/img835/6175/shinyn.png') center no-repeat;
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: relative;
    width: 12px;
    height: 13px;
    display: inline-block;
}

ul.one li .diamond:hover{
    background: url('http://img42.imageshack.us/img42/3357/shinyo.png') center no-repeat;
}

ul.one li .diamond:hover > .message{
    display: block;
}

ul.one .message{
    position: absolute;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    margin-top: 5px;
    top: 100%;
    left: -56.5px;
    z-index: 1;
    display: none;
    width: 125px;
}
```

---

### [Second example](http://jsfiddle.net/uZjz9/) | Code

HTML

```
<ul class="one">
    <li class="one">
        <input type="button"  id="1"onclick="show_prompt()" value="Minestatus" />
        <div class='message'>Please vote for me!</div>
    </li>
    <li class="two">
        <input type="button" id="2" onclick="show_alert()" value="Minecraft Server List" />
        <div class='message'>Please vote for me!</div>
    </li>
    <li class="three">
        <input type="button" id="3" onclick="show_alert1()" value="MCSL" />
        <div class='message'>Please vote for me!</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul.one {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

ul.one li{
    background: url('http://img835.imageshack.us/img835/6175/shinyn.png') left no-repeat;
    padding-left: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

ul.one li:hover{
    background: url('http://img42.imageshack.us/img42/3357/shinyo.png') left no-repeat;
}

ul.one li:hover > .message{
    display: block;
}

ul.one .message{
    position: absolute;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    display: none;
    width: 125px;
}
```

---

### [Third example](http://jsfiddle.net/uZjz9/2/) | Code

The third example uses javascript onmouseover/out events to keep track of the message triggering.

Same HTML as First example except I added an id to the list.

CSS

```
ul.one {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

ul.one li .diamond{
    background: url('http://img835.imageshack.us/img835/6175/shinyn.png') center no-repeat;
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: relative;
    width: 12px;
    height: 13px;
    display: inline-block;
}

ul.one li .hovering{
    background: url('http://img42.imageshack.us/img42/3357/shinyo.png') center no-repeat;
}

ul.one .message{
    position: absolute;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    margin-top: 5px;
    top: 100%;
    left: -56.5px;
    z-index: 1;
    display: none;
    width: 125px;
}
```

Javascript

```
var eList = document.getElementById("list"),
    eItems = eList.getElementsByTagName("li");

for(i = 0; i < eItems.length; i++){
    eItems[i].onmouseover = function(event){
        var eDivs = this.getElementsByTagName("div");

        for(j = 0; j < eDivs.length; j++){
            if(eDivs[j].className.indexOf("diamond") >= 0){
                if(eDivs[j].className.indexOf("hovering") == -1) eDivs[j].className += " hovering";
            }

            if(eDivs[j].className.indexOf("message") >= 0){
                eDivs[j].style.display = "block";
            }
        }
    };

    eItems[i].onmouseout = function(event){
        var eDivs = this.getElementsByTagName("div");

        for(j = 0; j < eDivs.length; j++){
            if(eDivs[j].className.indexOf("diamond") >= 0){
                if(eDivs[j].className.indexOf("hovering") != -1) eDivs[j].className = eDivs[j].className.replace("hovering", "").replace(" ", "");
            }

            if(eDivs[j].className.indexOf("message") >= 0){
                eDivs[j].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lokase is correct, there isn't a way to add it to just the bullet. But, there is something that you could do to mimic this.

Instead of using list-style-image on a list-item, add a span tag inside your list-item, remove the list-style and attach the mouseover event to the span. So your list-item would look like:

```
<li class="one"><span>Please vote for my server!</span><input type="button"  id="1"onclick="show_prompt()" value="Minestatus" /></li>
```

And your CSS would change to:

```
<style type="text/css">
ul.one span { background:url('http://fun.resplace.net/Emoticons/Minecraft/Diamond.png') no-repeat left top; display: block; height: 12px; list-style: none; text-indent: -9999px; width: 12px;}
</style>
```

You will have to adjust the height and width to correspond to the height and width of your diamond image. And, have to adjust the list-item styles to account for padding and margin differences because the actual bullet will no longer be there.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure the mouseover cannot distinguish between the LIs bullet and the LIs text.

You can put a mouseover on each LI and pop up a message, the following code example is Jquery based, you could hack out something similar in raw javascript:

```
$('ul.one li').mouseover(function() {
    show_message('my_message');
});
```